# jQuery success handler not executed on production server, but works fine in dev

Tags: javascript, ajax, callback, http-headers, doctype

OK, this is a weird one.

Quick summary: I am using the SilverStripe CMS, and it loads the UI in its admin via a set of ajax lazy-loading panels. It all works great in dev. And the ajax call to get the data for the main panel is working in both. That is, it returns the data (html in this case) on both the dev and production server, with a 200 code (so Firebug says).

Now, in the handler there is a success, error, and complete function - success takes the data and creates the main content panel. On my local development server, both success and complete fire just fine. But in production, only complete fires, even though I can see with Firebug that the data is returning just fine (with 200 like I said). Why isn't success running? Sure, I COULD move the *success* logic to *complete*, but this server is likely to keep producing the problem.

Here are the response headers on the Dev ajax call:

```
Cache-Control     no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection        Keep-Alive
Content-Length    38407
Content-Type      text/html; charset=utf-8
Date              Thu, 02 Aug 2012 01:02:08 GMT
Expires           Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Keep-Alive        timeout=5, max=100
Pragma            no-cache
Server            Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/1.0.1c DAV/2 PHP/5.3.12
Set-Cookie        PastMember=1; expires=Wed, 31-Oct-2012 01:02:09 GMT; path=/; httponly
X-Controller      CMSPagesController
X-Include-CSS     /framework/admin/thirdparty/jquery-notice/jquery.notice.css?m=1340880397...
X-Include-JS      /framework/thirdparty/jquery/jquery.js?m=1340880400...
X-Powered-By      PHP/5.3.12
X-Title           SilverStripe - Pages
```

Here are the headers in production (obvious difference is encoding/compression):

```
Cache-Control     no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0, max-age=0
Connection        Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding  gzip
Content-Length    2796
Content-Type      text/html; charset=utf-8
Date              Thu, 02 Aug 2012 01:44:20 GMT
Expires           Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Keep-Alive        timeout=2, max=98
Pragma            no-cache
Server            Apache
Set-Cookie        PastMember=1; expires=Wed, 31-Oct-2012 01:44:22 GMT; path=/; httponly
Vary              Accept-Encoding
X-Controller      CMSPagesController
X-Include-CSS     /framework/admin/thirdparty/jquery-notice/jquery.notice.css?m=1342411329...
X-Include-JS      /framework/thirdparty/jquery/jquery.js?m=1342412461...
X-Mod-Pagespeed   0.10.21.2-1381
X-Title           SilverStripe - Pages
```

To make things really strange, I can "fix" the situation by breaking the document. If I add a character before DOCTYPE: `.<!DOCTYPE html>`, the success handler runs and the panels load. Remove the one character and the panels don't load anymore. I'm stumped :-/

==== EDIT ====

Here is the ajax handler, very vanilla, nothing special going on. I added the console for debugging. Error never runs, just *success* and *complete* on the dev server, only *complete* on production. Now my guess is that it's trying to validate the html based on the doctype (html5) and it's getting errors? I didn't think jQuery goes that far though.  Also, I'm going to turn off compression and a pagespeed module on production to see if that has an effect, since dev doesn't have those features.

```
$.ajax({
url: url,
complete: function() {
    self.removeClass('loading');
    if(window.console) console.log('complete');
},
success: function(data, status, xhr) {
    if(window.console) console.log('success');
    self.html(data);
},
error: function(){
    if(window.console) console.log('error');
}
});
```

Comment: What are you passing to [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)? Did you specify a `dataType`?

Comment: No, but remember I'm running the exact same code on the dev and production server. Only production is failing to run *success*. Also, I did try specifying `dataType:'html'` for the hell of it. No dice.

Comment: When a success callback for a jQuery.ajax() request is not fired, but the http request is returned successfully, it is usually because the request specified the dataType, and the response body in invalid against that type. But, even if that's not the cause here, it would help if you posted the parameters you are passing to the ajax call.

Comment: What makes this question interesting to me: adding a character before the HTML5-style DOCTYPE declaration would make the response body _invalid_. That makes me suspect that you are triggering some kind of recovery behavior in jQuery, but I would have to step through with the debugger to be sure.

Comment: Since I'm new it won't let me answer my own question yet. The problem is an apache mod called mod_pagespeed. Had to disable it. Details coming soon.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I figured it out finally. The problem is a mod for apache that is still in beta (at least with my host). You can read all about mod_pagespeed here: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/mod

Once I disabled that and restarted apache, viola, jQuery successfully read the html data and the events fired correctly and now panels are loading as they should. Why? For some reason the "optimization" that pagespeed was doing killed the html structure in some minute but apparently important way.

I had run the snippets through the w3c validator, both before and after pagespeed, and the same three errors are there. So in the end I'm not sure exactly how pagespeed was screwing things up, I just know that it was, for what it's worth.